# elegant means of replacing multiple strings in body of http data sources

Tags: terraform

I have the following code, and whilst it works, I want to replace other strings in the all.yml file, is there a more elegant means of doing this other than to use nested replace statements ?

```
data "http" "all_yml" {
  url = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubespray/kubespray/master/inventory/sample/group_vars/all/all.yml"
}

resource "local_file" "all_yml" {
  content  = replace(replace(data.http.all_yml.body, "/#   - 8.8/", "  - 8.8"), "/# upstream_dns_servers/", "upstream_dns_servers")
  filename = local.all_conf_file
}
```

Comment: Have you tried with `response_body` instead of `body`?

Comment: I should do that